# Extract 1 or more specifically defined rectangular regions of a video file into a separate video file

Tags: video, motion-detection

I need a tool (preferably a GUI based one) that will help me easily define/select 1 or more rectangular regions/areas of interest in a video and then extract these regions/area in (a) separate file(s).

My main goal is to run a motion detection tool on a very long video file, but to only analyze several parts/regions/areas of the video screen.

Thank you